# Как настроить редирект nginx?

Tags: nginx

Начал знакомство с nginx и столкнулся с проблемой редиректа с http на  https, с www на без.

Точнее всё это сделал, но не идёт редирект если https://www.domain.com/
В этом случае редирект на https без www не делается.

Вот как выглядит у меня правило:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Как сделать что бы корректно работало?

Comment: listen 443 ssl очевидно

Answer (score 0):

```
server {

  listen 80;

  server_name www.domain.com;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

server {

  listen 443 ssl;

  if ($http_host = www.domain.com) {
    return 301 https://domain.com$uri;
  }

  ...

}
```